# Is there any other Middle Eastern country besides Iran that has been critical of the U.S. strikes in Yemen?

Tags: international, middle-east, yemen

> Tehran, Iran —
>
> Iran on Sunday denounced the latest U.S. and U.K. strikes on targets
> in Yemen saying they "contradict" their declared intention of avoiding
> a wider Middle East conflict.
>
> These attacks are "in clear contradiction with the repeated claims of
> Washington and London that they do not want the expansion of war and
> conflict in the region," Iran's foreign ministry spokesman, Nasser
> Kanaani, said in a statement.
>
> He accused the United States and Britain of "fueling chaos, disorder,
> insecurity and instability" by supporting Israel in its war against
> Hamas militants in the Gaza Strip.

https://www.voanews.com/a/iran-says-yemen-strikes-contradict-us-uk-policy/7470551.html

Is there any other Middle Eastern that has been critical of the U.S. strikes in Yemen? Iran has been critical of the recent strikes in Yemen saying it might cause a wider war in the Middle East. China also has been critical. I am wondering if there are other Middle Eastern countries that have been critical of the U.S. strikes in Yemen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Algeria](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/europe/algeria-condemns-us-british-airstrikes-in-yemen-as-dangerous-escalation/3107736):

> Algeria described the US-British airstrikes in Yemen on Friday as a "dangerous escalation" that will undermine UN “efforts to find a solution to the conflict” in the country.
>
> The Foreign Ministry expressed in a statement the "deep concern and regret" about the airstrikes "that targeted several cities in the sisterly Republic of Yemen."

I'm fairly sure Syria did it too, even without searching for a statement, but [that](https://sana.sy/en/?p=323468) wasn't hard to find:

> Syria condemned the US- British air strikes on Yemeni cities and called this aggression against the Yemeni people a threat to security and stability in the Red Sea region and the navigation therein, Foreign and Expatriates Ministry said in a statement on Friday.
>
> “Syria considers this aggression a desperate attempt to divert the attention of world public opinion from the war crimes committed by “Israel” against the Palestinian people,” the statement read.

And so [did Iraq](https://www.rudaw.net/english/middleeast/120120241):

> Iraq’s foreign ministry on Friday condemned US and UK strikes on Iran-backed Houthi targets in Yemen, warning against the expansion of the conflict.
>
> “We condemn the aggression against Yemen and its sovereignty. We believe that expanding the scope of targets does not represent a solution to the problem, rather, it will lead to an expansion of the scope of the war,” read a statement from the Iraqi foreign ministry.

However, the latter statement also said that

> In the [same] statement, the Iraqi foreign ministry reaffirmed the importance of “preserving freedom of navigation in international waters.”

---

In somewhat more veiled terms, some [other] Gulf countries have been critical [too](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2024/jan/12/hezbollah-and-iran-condemn-us-and-uk-strikes-against-houthis):

> Oman, another key mediator in Yemen’s long-running civil war, expressed its “worry” at the strikes on Houthi rebel military targets that, according to the Houthis, left five people dead.
>
> The Gulf sultanate “can only condemn the use of military action by friendly countries” while Israel pursues war against Hamas in the Gaza Strip, a foreign ministry spokesperson said.
>
> Mohammed bin Abdulrahman Al Thani, the prime minister of Qatar, the site of a major US military base, had already urged the US not to resort to military action. He said: “From Qatar’s policy perspective, we never see a military action as a resolution. Our biggest worry is to have consequences that will keep us in a loop that will never end and will create real tension in the entire region.”
>
> Kuwait’s foreign ministry also expressed “great concern”. The kingdom called for “self-restraint and avoiding escalation”.

And Turkey:

> the most vocal criticism came from Turkey, a Nato member, where President Recep Tayyip Erdoğan said [the strikes] “are not proportional. All of these constitute disproportionate use of force.”
>
> “It is as if they aspire to turn the Red Sea into a bloodbath,” he said.

AFAICT though, the [statements](https://www.rudaw.net/english/middleeast/24012024) after [the later] meeting with Raisi don't mention the Houthis/Yemen.

As for the Saudis, their [statements](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/saudi-arabia-calls-restraint-after-air-strikes-yemen-2024-01-12/) resemble China's in more vaguely calling for an avoidance of escalation

> Saudi Arabia called for restraint and "avoiding escalation" in light of the air strikes launched by the United States and Britain against sites linked to the Houthi movement in Yemen, the kingdom's foreign ministry said on Friday.
>
> Saudi Arabia, which has in recent months engaged in peace talks with Yemen's Houthis, was closely monitoring the situation with "great concern," the foreign ministry said in a statement.
>
> "The kingdom emphasizes the importance of maintaining the security and stability of the Red Sea region, as the freedom of navigation in it is an international demand," the ministry added.

Saudi statements were not too different from their [similar calls](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/edge-over-red-sea-attacks-riyadh-seeks-contain-fall-out-2023-12-06/) before the US-UK air strikes on the Houthis. And in a Jan 20 [interview](https://www.reuters.com/world/middle-east/saudi-says-escalating-tensions-amid-houthi-attacks-us-strikes-are-dangerous-2024-01-20/):

> Saudi Arabia's foreign minister said the kingdom was "very worried" that tensions in the Red Sea amid attacks by Yemen's Houthis and U.S. strikes on Houthi targets could spiral out of control and escalate the conflict in the region.
>
> "I mean, of course, we are very worried. I mean, you know, we are in a very difficult and dangerous time in the region, and that's why we are calling for de-escalation," Prince Faisal bin Farhan told CNN 'Fareed Zakaria GPS' in an interview that will be aired on Sunday.
>
> "We of course, believe very much in the freedom of navigation. And that's something that needs to be protected. But we also need to protect the security and stability of the region. So we are very focused on de-escalating the situation as much as possible," he told CNN.